# Scraping a website where all the data is locked in an XML database?

Tags: web, download, screen-scraping

I am trying to download the full archive files of this website (http://www.afghanislamicpress.com/).

I tried using DeepVacuum (http://www.hexcat.com/deepvacuum/index.html) but the site is dynamic (I think that's the right word).

So you submit a form that gives the article archive, but it only spits out 5 at a time (i.e. per page) and then you have to click through. I want to download all the individual articles for the full data set, but don't want to manually click through.

I know there's some easy way to do this, but not entirely sure how.

Any suggestions for a novice at doing data scraping etc?

Comment: Do you know any programming languages? Have you considered hiring somebody?

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward solution would be to contact the owner of the website and request their permission to republish their articles, and ask for a digital copy.

You can certainly automate pulling down content that is paged, but it requires some programming effort.  The best tool for that imho is [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Please be sure and comply with copyright and licensing terms of the content you are downloading.